# Bad file descriptor on a python script but the output is correct

Tags: python

The output of the script below is correct, but everytime it prints a line it prints the error too.

```
import os

for pid in os.listdir ( '/proc' ) :
    if pid.isdigit ( ) :
        try :
            p = open ( os.path.join ( '/proc' , pid , 'cmdline' ) , 'r' )
            CMD = p.read ( )
            try:
                tty = os.ttyname ( int ( pid ) )
            except OSError as error:
                print(error)
            print ( int ( pid ) , CMD , tty )
            p.close()
        except OSError as error:
            continue
```

output:

```
(1, '/sbin/init\x00splash\x00', '/dev/pts/0')
(2, '', '/dev/pts/0')
[Errno 25] Inappropriate ioctl for device
(3, '', '/dev/pts/0')
[Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
(4, '', '/dev/pts/0')
[Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

etc....
```

Comment: This won't be the correct output. Every time an `OSError` happens, `tty` won't be set. That means that the `tty` being printed out is whatever is was last time an error didn't happen. If the output is what you expect, that's a coincidence.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks for the reply,  but why this happens if I call os.ttyname(PID).
any ideas to imporove my script?

Comment: What you're doing here doesn't make sense; ttyname doesn't take a process ID, it takes a file descriptor, it can only tell you about file descriptors owned by the current process

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing error because specified file descriptor is not associated with any terminal device.

```
>>> r, w = os.pipe() 
>>> os.ttyname(r)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 25] Inappropriate ioctl for device
>>> r
6
>>> os.ttyname(6)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 25] Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

When it is associated.

```
>>> import os
>>> master, slave = os.openpty() 
>>> os.ttyname(master)
'/dev/ptmx'
>>> master
4
>>> os.ttyname(4)
'/dev/ptmx'
```

[Source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-ttyname-method/)

Some minor improvement on snippet shared:

```
import os

for pid in os.listdir('/proc' ):
    if pid.isdigit():
        try:
            with open(os.path.join('/proc', pid, 'cmdline'), 'r') as p:  # context way manages file close on its own
                CMD = p.read()
                tty = os.ttyname(int(pid))
                print(f"PID: {int( pid )}, CMD: {CMD}, TTY: {tty}")
        except OSError as error:  # Can be handled with same Same exception
            print(error)
            # continue   # Since there are no further lines of code hence
```

Comment: is there a way to avoid all these errors? your script, as mine, gives me only the first two correct outputs